# Perl: safely make hash from list, checking for duplicates

Tags: perl, list, hash, duplicates, checked

In Perl if you have a list with an even number of elements you can straightforwardly convert it to a hash:

```
my @a = qw(each peach pear plum);
my %h = @a;
```

However, if there are duplicate keys then they will be silently accepted, with the last occurrence being the one used.  I would like to make a hash checking that there are no duplicates:

```
my @a = qw(a x a y);
my %h = safe_hash_from_list(@a);    # prints error: duplicate key 'a'
```

Clearly I could write that routine myself:

```
sub safe_hash_from_list {
    die 'even sized list needed' if @_ % 2;
    my %r;
    while (@_) {
        my $k = shift;
        my $v = shift;
        die "duplicate key '$k'" if exists $r{$k};
        $r{$k} = $v;
    }
    return %r;
}
```

This, however, is quite a bit slower than the simple assignment.  Moreover I do not want to use my own private routine if there is a CPAN module that already does the same job.

Is there a suitable routine on CPAN for safely turning lists into hashes?  Ideally one that is a bit faster than the pure-Perl implementation above (though probably never quite as fast as the simple assignment).

If I may be allowed a related follow-up question, I'm also wondering about a tied hash class which allows each key to be assigned only once and dies on reassignment.  That would be a more general case of the above problem.  Again, I can write such a tied hash myself but I do not want to reinvent the wheel and I would prefer an optimized implementation if one already exists.

Comment: What makes you think that is slow? I think you'd be hard pressed to find a module that is faster. You'd need to benchmark it, and I seriously doubt you would gain much from it. You could for example use [`List::MoreUtils` `uniq`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#uniq-LIST), e.g. `if (@a == uniq(@a))`. But that subroutine is pretty simple, `sub uniq { my %seen; grep { !$seen{$_}++ } @_; }`

Comment: It is perhaps as fast as it can be made to be, but certainly slower than the simple assignment %h = @a.  Testing @a == uniq(@a) doesn't do what I want because only the keys (the even-position elements) need to be unique, not the values.

Comment: Well, then you would know that `keys %h` should be equal to `@a / 2`, now wouldn't you?

Comment: Yes, the same thought occurred to me at the same moment ;-)

Comment: Great minds think alike. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick way to check that no keys were duplicate would be count the keys and make sure they are equal to half the number of items in the list:

```
my @a = ...;
my %h = @a;
if (keys %h == (@a / 2)) {
    print "Success!";
}
```

Comment: Naive question: and if the ARRAY have odd elements like `qw/a b c/` ?

Comment: Then you can't coerce it into the hash in the first place. `Odd number of elements in hash assignment`

Comment: @sputnick then last value for hash is undef and `warnings` complain. `keys %h` is 2 and `@a / 2` is 1.5

Comment: `LIST` version: `sub { my $h = shift; %$h = @_; warn("...") if keys(%$h) != @_/2; }->(my %h, LIST);`

Comment: ikegami: I think you need to pass the hash reference as the first argument.  But yes, this could become a general set_hash(\%h, k=>v...) routine which avoids the overhead of returning the hash by value.